# Edge browser can't detect span element while Chrome and Firefox can

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a simple test where I just want to check if log in was successful by clicking on one of the elements displayed after log in.

Test passes in Chrome and Firefox but fails in Microsoft Edge 18.18363 / Windows 10

```
The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

   | 'span'
 > |   withText('CONTRACTS')
```

I'm pretty new to TestCafe, is it something obvious I'm overlooking?

[all technologies used on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzE4E.png)

Comment: This behavior sounds like an issue. Would you please provide sample markup or a public URL where we can see this behavior and your sample testcase? Thank you in advance. In addition, make sure that you are using the latest testcafe version (1.8.2+).

Comment: Hi, I'm using TestCafe Studio 1.2.2 and can't find a way to update to 1.8.2+

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. In this case, you only need to provide the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like TestCafe support for MS Edge hit production with 1.8.0: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/releases/tag/v1.8.0

We use yarn as a dependency manager and would check the version of the dependency by running

```
$ yarn list testcafe
yarn list v1.22.0
warning Filtering by arguments is deprecated. Please use the pattern option instead.
└─ testcafe@1.8.2
✨  Done in 0.24s.
```

You can run `yarn upgrade testcafe` ([doc](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade)) to update the version within the range specified by `package.json`, which may or may not allow 1.8.0.

Depending on the amount of red tape on your development team, you could update to the latest release with `yarn upgrade testcafe --latest` but it's important to note that will update `package.json`, which will affect all team members. So I would suggest asking your team lead before pushing an updated `package.json`.

Oh, and if you use npm as a package manager instead of yarn, the commands would be different.

Check installed version: 
    `npm outdated`

Update testcafe: 
    `npm update testcafe`

Hope this helps! I compiled this knowledge thru lots of googling, e.g. "update node package specific version".